# Got Exception : Index -1 with size of 3

Tags: android, listview

I am populating a list by the following code . After populating the list , I have set it to a listView .

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        // Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(
        // Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

        Cursor smsInboxCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), new String[] {},
                "read = 1 and address='" + pre_address + "'", null, null);
        int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst())
            return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        smsBody = new ArrayList<String>();
        String fromNumber = "";
        do {
            if (pre_address.equals(smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress))) {
                String str = "SMS From: "
                        + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) + "\n"
                        + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
                fromNumber = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress);
                smsBody.add(smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody));
                // arrayAdapter.add(str);
            }
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
        try {
            Cursor smsInboxCursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
                    Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), new String[] {},
                    "read = 0 and address='" + pre_address + "'", null, null);
            indexBody = smsInboxCursor1.getColumnIndex("body");
            indexAddress = smsInboxCursor1.getColumnIndex("address");
            do {
                if (pre_address.equals(smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexAddress))) {
                    String str = "SMS From: "
                            + smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexAddress) + "\n"
                            + smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexBody) + " \n";
                    fromNumber = smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexAddress);
                    smsBody.add(smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexBody));
                    // arrayAdapter.add(str);
                }
            } while (smsInboxCursor1.moveToNext());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, " message is "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        arrayAdapter = new SmsArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, smsBody,
                fromNumber);
        smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        Toast.makeText(this, "The list size is " + smsBody.size(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But I have got the exception that "index -1 requested with a size of 3 " . Why do I get the exception ? How can I solve this ?

Comment: index -1 requested with a size of 3 "

Comment: post your log with the line wich generate the exception

Comment: how can I see my log that which line generate the exception ?

Comment: this line generates the exception . if (pre_address.equals(smsInboxCursor1.getString(indexAddress)))

Answer (score 2):

`int getColumnIndex (String columnName)`

*Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, **or -1 if the column doesn't exist.** If you expect the column to exist use getColumnIndexOrThrow(String) instead, which will make the error more clear.*

Even if it's not that function, functions of the type *getIndexOfSomething()* usually return -1 when nothing is found (because 0 is a valid index).

Answer (score 1):

You have a check on

```
if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst())
            return;
```

for the `read = 1` sms messages, but no such check for `read = 0` sms messages.

If your intention is to get a list consisting of all read messages and all unread messages, instead of `return` after the above check, you should skip to the second part to get the `read = 0` messages, and perform the same check of empty result on `smsInboxCursor1`.